# cannot set the value of string from the main class into setter

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class StudentTest{

  public static void main(String args[]){

    UnderGrad uG1 = new UnderGrad();
    uG1.setName("John");
    uG1.setMatric("0192345");

    System.out.println("Undergarduate Student Info");
    uG1.setCourse(new Course("CS1103",3));
    uG1.setCourse(new Course("IT4504",3));
    uG1.displayStudentInfo();

    System.out.println(" ");

    PostGrad pG1 = new PostGrad();
    pG1.setName("Sam");
    pG1.setMatric("G015466");
    pG1.setResearch("Empirical Software Engineering");
    pG1.setResearch("Data Mining");
    System.out.println("Postgrad Student Info");
    pG1.displayStudentInfo();
  }
}

public class Course{
  private String courseName;
  private int crhour;

  public Course(String n, int c){
    courseName = n;
    crhour = c;
  }

  public void setCourseName(String course){
    courseName = course;
  }

  public String getCourseName(){
    return courseName;
  }

  public void setCreditH(int c){
    crhour = c;
  }
}

public class Student{

  private String matric ="-matric required-";
  private String name="-name required-";

  public Student(){
  }

    public void setName(String n){
      if (n.matches("[a-zA-Z]+") == false)
        System.out.println("Invalid Name");
      else
        name = n;
    }
    public String getName(){
    return name;}


  public void setMatric(String m){
    matric = m;}
  public String getMatric(){
    return matric;}
}

      public class UnderGrad extends Student{
    private Course courseList[];
    private int index = 0;

    public UnderGrad(){
      Course courseList[] =new Course[7];}

  public void setCourse(Course courseName){
    //Course courseList[]= new Course[2];
    }

  public Course[] getCourse(){
  return courseList;}

  public void displayStudentInfo(){

    System.out.println("Name: "+getName());
    System.out.println("Matric: "+getMatric());
    System.out.println("Course List: "+getCourse());
      }}

  public class PostGrad extends Student{
    private String researchArea[];
    private int index = 0;

    public PostGrad()
 {
 researchArea = new String[5];
 }

  public void setResearch(String research){
      for(index=0;index<2;index++){
        researchArea[index]=research;}
    }

  public String[] getResearch(){
  return researchArea;}

  public void displayStudentInfo(){

    System.out.println("Name: "+getName());
    System.out.println("Matric: "+getMatric());
    System.out.println("Research List: "+getResearch());
      }}
```

Output:

Undergarduate Student Info

Name: John

Matric: 0192345

Course List: null

Postgrad Student Info

Name: Sam

Matric: G015466

Course List: [Ljava.lang.String;@2ac9fefa

The problem I cant get the value of String of the course an the research. What should I do?Should I use super reference?

Answer (score 6):

Here:

```
System.out.println("Course List: "+getCourse());
```

You're printing out the default `toString()` returned by an array of String. Don't do that. Iterate through the array and print each item or else use `java.util.Arrays.toString(...)`.

```
System.out.println("Course List: "+ java.util.Arrays.toString(getCourse()));
```

You will also need to give your Course class a valid `toString()` method, one that returns the courseName and perhaps the credit hours. Also I would change the course field to courses or courseList to reflect that it does not represent one single course but rather a collection of courses. Likewise the getter method should reflect the field name change.